# Verify if a modem supports caller-id or not

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I want to Know my modem support caller-id and show number or not 
I use this AT-command:

```
 AT+FCLASS=?
```

I know if that response contains 8 support voice but if modem dosnt support voice it means cant support caller-id too?
I use Conexant USB CX93010 ACF Modem

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore is off-topic here. There are other [se] sites that may be suitable, such as [su]. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are appropriate to ask here. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you by caller-id means the supplementary service called CLIP - Calling Line Identification Presentation (for GSM/UMTS networks). You can check if your modem supports this by running `AT+CLIP=?`. To enable `+CLIP: ...` unsolicited responses after `RING` run `AT+CLIP=1`. Read [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more details.